# How to call only a subset of validation methods when editting

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my Django app, I am using a model (let's call it Mymodel), and a form :

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    firstField(...)
    secondField(...)

class MymodelAddform(ModelForm):
    def clean_firstField(self):
        #stuff

    def clean_secondField(self):
        #stuff again

    def clean(self):
        #performs stuff with all the fields

    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
```

Now I want to add another form, `MymodelEditform`, based on Mymodel again, using only `secondField`, and only `secondField` validation

Two options I've considered (both do not work as I wrote them) :

```
class MymodelEditform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ['secondField']
```

Here the problem is that `clean_secondField` is not called unless I re-define it, and I would like to avoid having `clean_secondField` call another method defined elsewhere (though, if it is the only option, so be it)

```
class MymodelEditform(MymodelAddform):
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ['secondField']
```

Here the problem is that the clean() validation is called, and since I'm only using a subset of the fields, it fails.

The question is pretty obvious : how can I make it work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but you can try this.

- Create a simple class with clean methods.

As below

```
class MymodelformCleaner(ModelForm):
    def clean_firstField(self):
        #stuff
    def clean_secondField(self):
        #stuff again
```

- Inherit your model forms from this class

Your model forms will just define the fields, while clean methods come from another class

```
class MymodelAddform(ModelForm, MymodelformCleaner):
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel

class MymodelEditform(ModelForm, MymodelformCleaner):
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ['secondField']
```

Comment: Well, I don't see the difference with the second option I showed : all validation methods will be called anyway, not just the ones related to `secondField`

Comment: No I don't think. In your way you are deriving from `MymodelAddform` which has all fields and might be calling clean for those fields. You may want to check how `Meta` class works with inheritance. In my case, the 2nd form has only one field, so should call only its clean method.

Comment: Explicitly specifying which fields to include already does what you are suggesting (it calls only the validation methods relevant to the fields you include). But I confused you by not testing enough the problem I was encountering. I've edited my question (actually, there is another clean() method)

Comment: @LogIn, In that case, I will suggest to define `clean` method only in `MymodelAddform` and not `MymodelformCleaner`.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious solution would be to define `clean_secondField` in `MymodelEditform` and make `MyModelAddForm` inherit from `MymodelEditForm`, but it might not work as expected. Another solution would be to make both forms inherit from a common base form defining clean_secondField.

Or you could just explicitely exclude the field in the form's Meta (cf https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12901)

Comment: I did exclude the field in the form's meta, but I just noticed I have also declared a clean() method that uses most of the fields in my model. It is this clean() method that breaks the thing (and not, as I thought in the first place, clean_firstfield). Is there a way to not include it when I make the editform inherit from the addform? The other solutions are, as you said, obvious, but it requires putting in different places code that should (IMO) be in the same place.

Comment: The usual solution is the TemplateMethod pattern... Oh wait... `form.clean_XXX` actually IS an implementation of the TemplateMethod pattern. Why not use it and put your `secondField`'s validation logic in `clean_secondField' ?
More seriously: do you have any reason to use two different forms ? Except from hidding a couple fields I mean ?

Comment: secondField's whole validation logic is already in clean_secondField. The problem is that the clean() method is called, and this one performs validations for other fields, in the way advised by django's doc ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other ). And no, I have no other reason to use two different forms except from hiding most of the fields. But I thought that was the only way : how can I do that without two forms?